# Prompt the user to type in a character/string and tell whether the input is in a given string

Tags: javascript, html

I need to create two functions, to request the user to type in a character and a string.
The inputs are matched with a given string.

Then tell the user, if the input character/string is found in the default given string.

So far I have created the basics to get the user inputs, but couldn't find any method to implement the javascript functions.
Any help would be highly appreciated.

Here's my code so far..!

```html
<html lang="en"> 
    <head> 
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width shrink-to-fit=no initial-scale=1">
        <title>Web Programming is fun!</title>

        <link rel="stylesheet"
            href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
            integrity="sha384-B0vP5xmATw1+K9KRQjQERJvTumQW0nPEzvF6L/Z6nronJ3oUOFUFpCjEUQouq2+l"
            crossorigin="anonymous"
        >
        <style>
            p{display: inline;}
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <h1>Web Programming is Fun!</h1>
            <br>
            <p>Lets use the above heading string to demonstrate inbuilt methods.</p>
           
            <label for="inputCharacter">Please type a character: </label>
            <input type="text" id="inputCharacter">
            <button onclick="matchCharacter()">Match Character</button>
            <p id="character"></p>

            <br>

            <label for="inputString">Please type a string: </label>
            <input type="text" id="inputString">
            <button onclick="matchString()">Match String</button>
            <p id="string"></p>
          
            <script>
                let text ="Web programming is fun!";
                function matchCharacter()
                {
                    var char=document.getElementById("inputCharacer").innerHTML;

                    if(char.indexOf(text) )
                    {
                       alert("Your Character is found in the string!")
                    }
                }

                function matchSring()
                {
                    
                }
            </script>
        </div>
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js"
         integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj"
         crossorigin="anonymous">
        </script>
        <script
         src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"
         integrity="sha384-Piv4xVNRyMGpqkS2by6br4gNJ7DXjqk09RmUpJ8jgGtD7zP9yug3goQfGII0yAns"
         crossorigin="anonymous">
        </script>
    </body>
        
</html>
```

Comment: You need to have actually attempted something in order for us to help you...

Comment: I have edited my matchCharacter() function, that's all I've got in my mind as I'm quite new to html and javascript

Comment: Use `.value` to get the value typed into your fields, not `.innerHTML`. Also, your element ID is `inputCharacter`, not `inputCharacer`

Comment: You also have a typo: `inputCharacer` should be `inputCharacter`.

Comment: I've corrected the typo and made the changes. But, whenever I press the button, the message is alerted, not matching the input character to the string

Comment: you can also use `find()` function to find for some specific elements

Answer (score 1):

I think you have inverted the parameters. Instead of char.indexOf you should use text.indexOf.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf

```html
<html lang="en"> 
    <head> 
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width shrink-to-fit=no initial-scale=1">
        <title>Web Programming is fun!</title>

        <link rel="stylesheet"
            href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
            integrity="sha384-B0vP5xmATw1+K9KRQjQERJvTumQW0nPEzvF6L/Z6nronJ3oUOFUFpCjEUQouq2+l"
            crossorigin="anonymous"
        >
        <style>
            p{display: inline;}
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <h1>Web Programming is Fun!</h1>
            <br>
            <p>Lets use the above heading string to demonstrate inbuilt methods.</p>
           
            <label for="inputCharacter">Please type a character: </label>
            <input type="text" id="inputCharacter" maxLength="1">
            <button onclick="matchCharacter()">Match Character</button>
            <p id="character"></p>

            <br>

            <label for="inputString">Please type a string: </label>
            <input type="text" id="inputString">
            <button onclick="matchString()">Match String</button>
            <p id="string"></p>
          
            <script>
                let text ="Web Programming is Fun!";
                function matchCharacter()
                {
                    var char=document.getElementById("inputCharacter").value;

                    
                    if(text.indexOf(char) != -1)
                    {
                       alert("Your Character is found in the string!")
                    } else {
                      alert("Your Character is not found in the string!")
                    }
                }

                function matchString()
                {
                    var string=document.getElementById("inputString").value;

                
                if(text.indexOf(string) != -1)
                {
                   alert("String Found in heading!")
                } else {
                  alert("String not found in the heading!")
                }
                }
            </script>
        </div>
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js"
         integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj"
         crossorigin="anonymous">
        </script>
        <script
         src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"
         integrity="sha384-Piv4xVNRyMGpqkS2by6br4gNJ7DXjqk09RmUpJ8jgGtD7zP9yug3goQfGII0yAns"
         crossorigin="anonymous">
        </script>
    </body>
        
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Inside your javascript you can replace *innerHTML* to *value* attribute to access user input and then match that character.
And also you are calling indexOf on character but you have to call it on the *text* variable that you have created.

```
              
                <script>
                    let text ="Web programming is fun!";
                    function matchCharacter()
                    {
                        var char=document.getElementById("inputCharacer").value;

                        if(text.indexOf(char) !== -1)
                        {
                           alert("Your Character is found in the string!");
                           return true;
                        }
                        return false;

                    }

                    function matchSring()
                    {
                         if (matchCharacter()) console.log("Character is found");
                         else console.log("Character is not found");
                    }
                </script>
```